# what is difference between i18n message key hierarchy and global resource properties

Tags: web, struts2

today i am testing 1 by 1 each every thing working fine but i am confused when i reached at 7th 
as i know 
Resource bundles are searched in the following order:

1. ActionClass.properties
2. Interface.properties (every interface and sub-interface)
3. BaseClass.properties (all the way to Object.properties)
4. ModelDriven's model (if implements ModelDriven), for the model object repeat from 1
5. package.properties (of the directory where class is located and every parent directory all  the way to the root directory)
6. search up the i18n message key hierarchy itself
7. global resource properties

what is different between 6 and 7 if i use

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>struts.custom.i18n.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>res</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and define res.properties in resources folder it will take values. is this one is 6th or 7th way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In step 6 struts looks for property files of domain object on the value stack:
For example if you have a "user" property on the value stack and a key "user.name" then struts searches a properties file "User.properties" with a message with key "name" (not "user.name").

In step 7 your global config file (which you named "res.properties") will be used.

BTW: There's a nice explanation of this process in the book "Struts 2 in Action".